# PHP: find array element by string selector

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I trying to understand the way I can find element in a multidimensional array using "selector".

```
$vars = array(
    'site' => 'Stackoverflow',
    'menu' => array(
        'items' => array('Questions', 'Tags', 'Users', 'Badges', 'Unanswered'),
    ),
    'sidebar' => array(
        'tags' => array(
            'c_sharp' => 68,
            'java' => 62,
            'javascript' => 52,
            'jquery' => 50
        )
    )
);
```

I would like to have some function `mixed find(string $selector, array $array)`.

**Usage**

```
$site = find('site', $vars);
// result: "Stackoverflow"

$menuItems = find('menu.items', $vars);
// result: ["Questions", "Tags", "Users", "Badges", "Unanswered"]

$tags = find('sidebar.tags', $vars);
// result: ["c_sharp" => 68, "java" => 62, "javascript" => 52, "jquery" => 50]

$javascriptQuestionsCount = find('sidebar.tags.javascript', $vars);
// result: 52

$undefinedElement = find('footer.copyright.year', $vars);
// result: null
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to implement such function or maybe there are some ready-made solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Laravel has a function that does exactly this, it's called [array_get()](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/helpers.php#L59-78)

Comment: Have you tried to implement it? From what I see you only need to `explode('.',$selector)`, which seems quite straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has a function that does exactly this, it's called [array_get()](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/helpers.php#L59-78)

You'll probably want to ignore the `value()` function, but you could just `return $default;` instead.

---

```
/**
 * Get an item from an array using "dot" notation.
 *
 * <code>
 *      // Get the $array['user']['name'] value from the array
 *      $name = array_get($array, 'user.name');
 *
 *      // Return a default from if the specified item doesn't exist
 *      $name = array_get($array, 'user.name', 'Taylor');
 * </code>
 *
 * @param  array   $array
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function array_get($array, $key, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) return $array;

    // To retrieve the array item using dot syntax, we'll iterate through
    // each segment in the key and look for that value. If it exists, we
    // will return it, otherwise we will set the depth of the array and
    // look for the next segment.
    foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment)
    {
        if ( ! is_array($array) or ! array_key_exists($segment, $array))
        {
            return value($default);
        }

        $array = $array[$segment];
    }

    return $array;
}

/**
 * Return the value of the given item.
 *
 * If the given item is a Closure the result of the Closure will be returned.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return mixed
 */
function value($value)
{
    return (is_callable($value) and ! is_string($value)) ? call_user_func($value) : $value;
}
```

Comment: One question though... What does exactly `value($default)` do?

Comment: @Havelock `call_user_func` if value `is_callable` otherwise just returns it

Comment: I just thought you should maybe add this function as well, otherwise the OP will copy/paste your code snippet and will come back later with the next problem, i.e. `Call to undefined function value()` ;-)

Comment: @Havelock I did note in my answer that you can replace the value function, and the OP in this case has already found the value function themselves.  But I've added it for completeness anyway ;-)

Comment: My bad, must've missed it ;-)

Comment: @balkon_smoke did this answer your question?  You've not marked anything as solved yet.

Comment: @PhillSparks yep, very sorry - just forgot

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
   <?php
$vars = array(
    'site' => 'Stackoverflow',
    'menu' => array(
        'items' => array('Questions', 'Tags', 'Users', 'Badges', 'Unanswered'),
    ),
    'sidebar' => array(
        'tags' => array(
            'c_sharp' => 68,
            'java' => 62,
            'javascript' => 52,
            'jquery' => 50
        )
    )
);

function find ($key, $array){
  $keys = explode(".",$key);
    $currArr = $array;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($keys);$i++){
        if (isset($currArr[$keys[$i]])){
          $currArr = $currArr[$keys[$i]];
        }else{
          return null;
        }
    }

    return $currArr;
}

$site = find('site', $vars);
print_r($site);
echo "<br />";

$menuItems = find('menu.items', $vars);
print_r($menuItems);
echo "<br />";

$tags = find('sidebar.tags', $vars);
print_r($tags);
echo "<br />";

$javascriptQuestionsCount = find('sidebar.tags.javascript', $vars);
print_r($javascriptQuestionsCount);
echo "<br />";

$undefinedElement = find('footer.copyright.year', $vars);
print_r($undefinedElement);
echo "<br />";
?>
```

Output:

```
Stackoverflow
Array ( [0] => Questions [1] => Tags [2] => Users [3] => Badges [4] => Unanswered ) 
Array ( [c_sharp] => 68 [java] => 62 [javascript] => 52 [jquery] => 50 ) 
52
null
```

Fiddle:

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/u7u-8jx

Works without any lib, just plain PHP.